# Why a job in Laravel queue retry a Guzzle http request was successful with status 200

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-queue, guzzle

I have a Laravel application and one process put a job on laravel queue. The job trying to execute an asynchronous post http request. When the request fail I catch the exception without problem, but when I have a status 200, the application log the response but few seconds later try to execute again the request.

My request:

```
 class NotifyPayment implements ShouldQueue {
    
     /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(SettlementModel $settlement) {
        $this->settlement = $settlement;
    }

     /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle() {

        $settlement = $this->settlement;

        $id = $settlement->id;
        Log::info("Executing job: ".$settlement->id);
        $client = new Client(); 
        try {
            
            $promise = $client->requestAsync('POST', $settlement->siam_response_url);
            $promise->then(
                function (ResponseInterface $res) use ($id) {
                    Log::info('Status:'.$res->getStatusCode().', NOTIFY SUCCESS: '.$id.'
                    ');
                }
            );
            $promise->wait();
        }
        catch (RequestException $e)
        {   
            Log::error("NOTIFY WAS FAILED: ID ".$settlement->id." ".$e->getMessage());
            Log::error( $e->getRequest()->getMethod()." ".$e->getMessage() . "\n");
            $this->job->fail(null);
        }


    }
}
```

And this is my log file:

[2020-09-10 12:21:16] production.INFO: Settlement paid: 22638

***[2020-09-10 12:21:17] production.INFO: Executing job: 23423***

***[2020-09-10 12:21:18] production.INFO: Status:200, NOTIFY SUCCESS: 22638***

***[2020-09-10 12:23:02] production.INFO: Executing job: 23423***

***[2020-09-10 12:23:03] production.ERROR: NOTIFY WAS FAILED: ID 22638 Client error: `POST https://some-url-of-my-system/callback-paid?token=8832fa192f059598e064b905` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response***

[2020-09-10 12:23:03] production.ERROR: POST Client error: `POST https://some-url-of-my-system/callback-paid?token=8832fa192f059598e064b90524dc018ad1331f763e5c45ba21470e0112645f4f22dbb703468998e22cfcb4fe6ce328db9a730e900bbb75757aba3a97210810ef` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response

With this log

```
Log::info("Executing job: ".$settlement->id);
```

I can see that the jobs was executed two times, whats happening here?

And where raise the notification is here:

```
NotifyPayment::dispatch($settlement);
```

**PD:** the url of the post request only can executed once, the second time throw a status 400.

**IMPORTANT INFORMATION**

When my process start, that was start in this route `/cashier` and when the process did all the steps, run the job queue, etc etc. redirect at the same route  `/cashier`

```
return redirect()
            ->route('cashier')
            ->withMessages(['type' => 'success', 'text' => 'The payment was successful!!!']);
```

Comment: timeout and retry_after settings are set to?

Comment: Are settings by default, how much time I need set to? Because my http request respond in one or two seconds at max

Comment: it is a common error for job executing multiple times, check for the key retry_after in queue config under redis.

Comment: Sorry that is a legacy project and I a noob in Laravel, where I can see that configuration? in my .env file? or where?

Comment: config/queue.php

Comment: Thanks a lot @mrhn

Comment: Did you find the retry after? Did you solve it or how goes?

Comment: I did the changes and I have the same issue.. 
This is my configuration in queue.php


`'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'default',
            //'retry_after' => 90, old_configuration
            'retry_after' => 300,
        ],`

And add to this values in my **class NotifyPayment implements ShouldQueue**

    public $timeout = 300;

    public $retryAfter = 300;

Answer (score 0):

When my process starts, that was start in this route /cashier and when the process did all the steps, run the job queue, etc etc. redirect at the same route /cashier

I only was changed the redirect route to the job on the queue run only once time.
I don't know why the job run twice when you start in a route and after finish your process go to the same route.

The solution:

Change this

```
return redirect()
            ->route('cashier')
            ->withMessages(['type' => 'success', 'text' => 'The payment was successful!']);
```

to this:

```
return redirect()
            ->route('cashier.details') //to any other route from you app
            ->withMessages(['type' => 'success', 'text' => 'The payment was successful!']);
```